# Can I create a new table in my function to make a bar chart to output in dash callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have my user inputs of month and country. I want to filter my data to the selected month and country then apply two different group bys and calculations afterwards to create two new data frames. The code runs but when I select the filters, nothing is outputting in the chart.

Here's what the data is like:
[Screenshot of Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUTEU.png)

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output, dcc

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    'Month', 
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'month_dd',
        options = list(df['Month'].unique()), 
        multi = True),  
    'Country', 
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'country_dd', 
        options = list(df['COUNTRY_NAME'].unique()), 
        multi = True),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Input('month_dd', 'value'), 
    Input('country_dd', 'value'))

def coverage_rate(month, country):
    # Select filters to apply to dataframe
    month_mask = df['Month'].isin(month)
    country_mask = df['COUNTRY_NAME'].isin(country)
    
    filtered_df = df[country_mask & month_mask]

    grouped_df = filtered_df.groupby(['SKU']).agg({'quantity': 'sum','price': 'mean'}).reset_index()
    grouped_df['retail'] = grouped_df['quantity'] * grouped_df['price']
    total_retail = grouped_df['retail'].sum()

    compet_grouped_df = filtered_df.groupby(['SKU', 'Compet SKU', 'Brand']).agg({'quantity': 'sum','price': 'mean'}).reset_index()
    compet_grouped_df['retail'] = compet_grouped_df['quantity'] * compet_grouped_df['price']
    compet_total_retail = compet_grouped_df.groupby('Brand').agg({'retail': 'sum'}).reset_index()
    
    compet_grouped_df['index'] = pd.Series(dtype = 'float')

    for index, row in compet_grouped_df.iterrows(): 
        compet_grouped_df['index'][index] = row['retail']/total_retail*100

    fig = px.bar(
        compet_grouped_df, 
        x = 'Brand', 
        y = 'index')
    return fig 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Can you show us your dataset? In your code there is an undefined variable called `df`. This will allow us to replicate your code locally.

Comment: @AndreVale69 I added a screenshot of what df looks like